# Error while importing a SQL file to hostgator phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I encountered the error below while trying to import a SQL file to my hostgator phpmyadmin, the file was exported from my previous webhost.

> Error
>
> SQL query:
>
> phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>   -- version 4.0.10.7
>
> ### -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
>
> -- Host: localhost
>   -- Generation Time: Nov 19, 2015 at 06:26 AM
>   -- Server version: 5.5.32-cll-lve
>   -- PHP Version: 5.4.23
>
> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>   -- version 4.0.10.7
>
> ### -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
>
> -- Host:' at line 1

Comment: To which MySQL version are you trying to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'm able to fix the error by opening the exported SQL file on Dreamweaver and then saved it with another name through 'Save As', it sounds stupid but it helped solved most of the #1064 errors.